# React native : Problem Loading Fonts in a custom Hook

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying To make a custom hook that loads fonts using `{useFonts}` from expo, so that i wont have to repeat the code evrytime, and here is what I got so far.

```js
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

export default useAppFonts = () => {
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    RobotoSlabBlack: require("../Fonts/RobotoSlab-Black.ttf"),
    RobotoSlabBold: require("../Fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf"),
    RobotoSlabExtraBold: require("../Fonts/RobotoSlab-ExtraBold.ttf"),
    RobotoSlabExtraLight: require("../Fonts/RobotoSlab-ExtraLight.ttf"),
    RobotoSlabThin: require("../Fonts/RobotoSlab-Thin.ttf"),
    RobotoSlabRegular: require("../Fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  return loaded;
};
```

the problem is that it works the first time I load the app but when I reload it stops working and the text reverts back to default fonts.

making a custom text component with the fonts already it came to mind, but it really bothers me that I can't do it like this.

and if its not possible I would like to know that, thank you for anyone with a response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `loadAsync` instead of `useFonts`

To `loadFonts` which I do in all my project is create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located

Then, Install `expo-app-loading` & `expo-font`

Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";
    
export default useFonts = async () => {
    await Font.loadAsync({
        "Montserrat-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf")
    });
};.
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';
    
export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);
    
  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };
    
  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
     );
  }
    
  return <View styles={styles.container}>{/* Your App Code Here */}</View>;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i ll try this as soon as possible.